# What is the best joinery method for a cantilever leg support to secure a 2X10'' wood leg to a 3/4''18''X20'' wood flat base end

Tags: joinery

The cantilever support leg is 2 X 10'' fir/spruce attached to underside of coffee table on cleat mounting blocks. The lower part of the leg is to be flanged secured to the flat base at bottom on one end. The flat panel hardwoo base is 18'' X 20'' and is only **3/4''** thick

Comment: An illustration or a sketch will help us to understand your design concept.

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackExchange. *"What is the best joinery method for a cantilever leg support"* Depends who you're asking. As worded this is asking for opinions, or [every answer is equally valid](https://woodworking.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask). Just generally, there is almost never **a** best option, but rather a number of good options that you simply pick from based on *your* opinion/like the look of/is within your current skillset. Also, you're not designing this in a vacuum.... what I'm getting at is how have other makers who have built similar things tackled the problem?

Comment: OP hasn't been back to update the question in 2 weeks, :( VtC...